# CSS Transitions Animate When Div No Longer Being Hovered

Tags: css

Hello I was working on this and I got it to smoothly animate when hovered I was wondering if there is a way so that it will animate back to 0 smoothly when it is no longer being hovered?
http://jsfiddle.net/KeenanGalipeault/gY82Q/

```
<div></div>

div {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: #262626;
transition: 0.6s;
}
div:hover {
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
border: 12px solid #0071bc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS transitions works better if both the 'ends' of the transition are explicit, in this case everything works fine by adding  `border: 0 solid #0071bc;` to the first selector, here's the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gY82Q/1/

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #262626;
     box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    transition: 0.6s;
    border: 0 solid #0071bc;
}
div:hover {
    border: 12px solid #0071bc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an initial **border** for the transition to have an "out" reference, like this:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #262626;
    transition: 0.6s;
    border: 0 solid /* This is the initial border you have to add. 
                   Just add  a size (0) and a style (solid). 
                   No need to add an initial color, 
                       as in this case it'll be shown in the default 
                           state.*/
}

div:hover {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 12px solid #0071bc;
}
```

Here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gY82Q/2/

Comment: If you want to reduce the code size you could replace **300px** with **18em/19em**, **#262626** with **#222** (they are very similar as colors) and **0.6s** with **.6s**